# Do all C++/CLI objects require disposal?

Tags: .net, c++-cli, idisposable

My understanding ([partly from reading threads here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4935305/5869304)) is that every C++/CLI object in the world automatically implements IDisposable by virtue of its C++/CLI destructor.

My [further understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1125745/5869304) is that whenever your managed class A uses an instance of another managed class B which implements IDisposable, it becomes your responsibility to implement IDisposable *somewhere* (or use a "using" statement) to ensure that B.Dispose is called.

Are these both correct?  If so, then that means that basically anytime I use a C++/CLI object anywhere my C# code, I need an IDisposable implementation or a using to clean it up.  Yes?

This I did not realize

In my current app design, none of my C# classes really "own" any of the C++/CLI object instances they use.  I tend to create and pass them around freely.  A C# object of class "A" might create a C++/CLI object and then hand it off to instances of C# class "B" and "Z".  All 3 might store references to it   So none of them can call Dispose on it because none of them owns it.

So effectively I've got a whole bunch of IDisposable C++/CLI objects and nobody is ever calling Dispose on them.

I thought this was fine.  Only a few of my C++/CLI classes allocate a significant portion of memory.

Is this something I should be at all concerned about?  Should I be looking to try to rearchitect my app so that each C++/CLI object is owned by one and only one C# object so I can implement IDisposable on the C# classes and dutifully call Dispose on the underlying C++/CLI instances?

Comment: No, you don't *have* to write a destructor.  In practice a C++/CLI wrapper always requires a finalizer, !classname, to destroy a pointer to a native C++ object that gets wrapped.  That tends to make it sensible to also write the destructor.  Unless it is not sensible, when the native C++ object takes very little space for example.  Or when GC::AddMemoryPressure() can't get the job done.  It often does, but isn't considered often enough.  A destructor is a pita to the client code.

Comment: And do keep in mind that this has *nothing* to do with how much space your C++/CLI class object takes.  That's taken care of by the garbage collector.  Only the unmanaged resources you wrap need to be considered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is, "no", all CLI classes do not require disposal. Disposal is only needed when UNmanaged resources come into play. For example, a file handle, or memory which was allocated on an unmanaged heap.

Edit...

I don't believe that "every C++/CLI class in the world implements IDisposable by design" is a true statement. It would be accurate to say that "every C++/CLI class *which declares a finalizer* implements IDisposable". When, in C++, you `delete` a managed object, its destructor is called, which should in turn call its own finalizer. When, in C# (for example), you call `Dispose()` (either explicitly or via a `using` block), its finalizer will be called, which effectively means it implements IDisposable. If there's no finalizer, the object cannot be properly disposed from a language such as C#.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/ms177197(v=vs.100)

Comment: Well then what about the admonishment that one must implement IDisposable whenever member data -- even *managed* members -- also implement IDisposable.  Every C++/CLI class in the world implements IDisposable by design (if I understand correctly)

Comment: Ah I get it now.  I was under the impression that you essentially got a destructor in C++/CLI (and therefore you automatically implemented IDisposable)  whether you declared one or not.  I guess I'm thinking too much like a C++ programmer